# How to display content under ttk treeview sun tree

Tags: python, tkinter

I have these few lines of code where i want my gender content to display under treeview sub tree on the same row as the name there but it displays
on new rows after the subtree.

Want it to display as the example below:

`FRED                        MALE`

`MAVIS                       FEMALE`

`FRED                        OTHER`

on same row under the subtree but not able to achive that.

Your suggestions are welcome to achieve that.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x680+50+20")


tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
    ############
tree.config(columns=("col1","col2","col3"))   


#SUb treeview
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure("Treeview", rowheight=30)
tree.configure(style="Treeview")


tree.heading("#1", text="DOB")
tree.heading("#2", text="SCHOOL")
tree.heading("#3", text="GENDER")


tree.insert("", "0", "item1", text="Names",)
tree.insert("", "1", "item2", text="Names")


tree.set("item1", "#1", ["2019-05-25"])
tree.set("item1", "#2", ["HARVARD"])


#sub tree using item attribute to achieve that
tree.insert("item1", "1", text="FRED")
tree.insert("item1", "1", text="MAVIS")
tree.insert("item1", "1", text="BRIGHT")


tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("", "", "MALE"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("", "", "OTHER"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("", "", "FEMALE"))




tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you can replace this:

```
tree.set("item1", "#1", ["2019-05-25"])
tree.set("item1", "#2", ["HARVARD"])


#sub tree using item attribute to achieve that
tree.insert("item1", "1", text="FRED")
tree.insert("item1", "1", text="MAVIS")
tree.insert("item1", "1", text="BRIGHT")


tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("", "", "MALE"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("", "", "OTHER"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("", "", "FEMALE"))
```

with this:

```
tree.insert("item1", "end", text="FRED", values=("2019-05-25", "HARVARD", "MALE"))
tree.insert("item1", "end", text="MAVIS", values=("2019-05-25", "HARVARD", "OTHER"))
tree.insert("item1", "end", text="BRIGHT", values=("2019-05-25", "HARVARD", "FEMALE"))
```